# Convert CSV column to list

Tags: python, arrays, list, csv

Say I have a CSV file. 
It contains:

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

How can I turn the column labeled 'a' into a list, without hard-coding a row to it?

Originally, I was doing a readline for the first line `a,b,c` and then hard-coding a row to each variable. But then I thought: what if I wanted to do it with the possibility of the CSV file not being arranged the same way - say:

```
b,a,c
2,1,3
5,4,6
8,7,9
```

What's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) turns each row of your CSV file into a dictionary with the column headers as keys. For your case (assuming the two examples in your question are named `abc.csv` and `bac.csv` respectively), you could use it like this:

```
from csv import DictReader

with open("abc.csv") as f:
    a1 = [row["a"] for row in DictReader(f)]

with open("bac.csv") as f:
    a2 = [row["a"] for row in DictReader(f)]

# a1 == a2 == ['1', '4', '7']
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do this using the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library:

```
import pandas

data = pandas.read_csv("test.csv", header=0)
col_a = list(data.a)
col_b = list(data.b)
col_c = list(data.c)
```

The values in `col_a`, `col_b` and `col_c` are as follows:

```
[1, 4, 7]
[2, 5, 8]
[3, 6, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import collections
my_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open('your_file') as f:
    header = next(f).strip().split(',')
    for x in f:
         x = x.strip().split(',')
         my_dict[header[0]].append(x[0])
         my_dict[header[1]].append(x[1])
         my_dict[header[2]].append(x[2])
```