# CSV columns into a list of lists without using pandas

Tags: python, csv

Say, I have an Excel file exported as a CSV file, 5 rows and 3 columns, with the following values:

```
1.0 0.0 5.0
2.0 0.0 4.0
3.0 0.0 3.0
4.0 0.0 2.0
5.0 0.0 1.0
```

I need to get a list of lists with the sorted values of the correlative columns (in this example 3 columns, but it could be more...), like:

```
OutputList = [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0]]
```

Unfortunately I cannot use Pandas. All answers I found were related to pandas or listing values in rows instead of columns (or code snippets that didn't work for me).

Comment: Then remove tag pandas

Comment: What about using csv reader? Have you looked at [this possible duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28283647/convert-csv-column-to-list)?

Comment: OK, thanks for the tip, @Wen

Comment: Does your file have a header?

Comment: No, it doesn't, @pault. That's why I posted the desired 'OutputList' including values in first row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using default `csv module`

**Demo:**

```
import csv
with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=' ')
    OutputList = [map(float, list(i)) for i in zip(*reader)]

print(OutputList)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0]]
```

*Edit as per comment.*

```
from itertools import izip_longest
import csv
with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=' ')
    OutputList = [map(float, [j for j in list(i) if j is not None]) for i in izip_longest(*reader)]

print(OutputList)
```

Comment: In python3 you need to use `list(map(float, list(i)))`

Comment: python3 `OutputList = [list(map(float, list(i))) for i in zip(*reader)]`

Comment: In Python 3, you should `open` csv files and specify `newline=''` according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) (see example code).

Comment: After trying a few times... finally i got it! with `delimiter=';'` It was the way the csv was actually stored. Thank you very much!

Comment: @martineau. Thanks, sorry I only have python2.7 in my machine.

Comment: Rakesh: In that case, it's still wrong. You should `open` the csv file in binary mode (see the Python 2 [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader)).

Comment: I noticed i'm forced to have the same number of values per column... if i have a column with 5 values and another column with 3 values only, I just got an error: `'WARNING: Script error: "could not convert string to float: "` Do you know how can I manage diferent sizes of columns in the same csv? Thank you very much in advance, one more time, @Rakesh

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach to your problem without using `pandas` or `csv`:

Read the file into a list of rows and then use `zip` to convert it into a list of columns:

```
delim = ";"  # based on OP's comment
with open("myfile") as f:
    OutputList = [[float(x) for x in line.split(delim)] for line in f]
OutputList = zip(*OutputList)

print(OutputList)
#[(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0),
# (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
# (5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0)]
```

This produces a list of tuples. If you wanted to change those to lists, you can easily convert them using:

```
OutputList = [list(val) for val in OutputList]
print(OutputList)
#[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0],
# [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
# [5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, mate. For some reason I just got ' WARNING: Script error: "invalid literal for float(): 1;2;5" at  line number 4' and I think it's related with the specification of the delimiter. Thank you very much anyway, mate!!

Comment: @Victor `str.split()` takes an optional delimiter argument (default is whitespace). I added an update to fix this for your code.

Answer (score 2):

You could try it with the defaul csv module and the `zip` function:

```
import csv
with open('book1.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    a = list(zip(*reader))
    for i in a:
        print(i)
```

Output is:

```
('1.0', '2.0', '3.0', '4.0', '5.0')
('0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0')
('5.0', '4.0', '3.0', '2.0', '1.0')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def sort_columns(myfile):
    # open the file with your data
    with open(myfile, "r") as f:
        # read the data into a "rows"
        rows = f.readlines()

    # store the number of columns or width of your file
    width = len(rows[0].split())
    # initialize your "result" variable that will be a list of lists
    result = []
    # initialize i to 0 and use it access each column value from your csv data
    i = 0
    while i < width:
        # initialize temp list before each while loop run
        temp = []
        # using list comprehension, store the i'th column from each row into temp
        temp = [ float(row.split()[i]) for row in rows if row.split() ]
        # temp now has the value of entire i'th column, append this to result
        result.append(temp)
        # increment i to access the next column
        i += 1
    # return your result
    return result

print sort_columns("file-sort-columns.txt")
```